# It brings me a little overlap confuse when use ui-view on a custom directive in Angular

Tags: angularjs, structure

All:

I am pretty new to angular ui-router, right now I have a very simple structure for a SPA:

```
<div class="mainbody">
    <nav-header></nav-header>
    <nav-body ui-view></nav-body>
    <nav-chat></nav-chat>
</div>
```

The logic on this view is simple:

3 customized directives:

```
nav-header
nav-body
nav-chat
```

Inside nav-header, there are search bar, signIn/signUp button, logOff if loggedIn.

Inside navBody, it should switch among userRegister/userLogIn page, userProfile(once logged in) and Biz Info page.

nav-chat need to hide before use logged in.

My confuse is:

> Is that nav-body unnecessary? Should I just need a ui-view which is
>   more than enough to handle the logic I talk about?
>
> I have no experience in app structure design, could anyone help or
>   give a general best practice for this structure design?

Thanks

Comment: To answer your first question ... nav-body does not need to be a directive to achieve what you want ... <ui-view></ui-view> should be enough.

Comment: @o4ohel Thanks, I will just use div ui-view instead